# How to validate array with RegExr laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am using laravel and I want to validate request like this

```
      'specification' => 'min:1|max:100000|regex:/^[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\- ]+$/u',
```

but it is as a array like this

[image]

it works well with string but not validate array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
'specification.*' => 'min:1|max:100000|regex:/^[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\- ]+$/u'
```

when you have an array from input then the `.*` applies the validation rule to every item in that array